# Reactjs Prop: Build an component Housefull

Tags: reactjs

Create a `HouseFull` component that has a boolean prop `hasSeat`. The component should render a `div` with either the text `Housefull` or `Vacant` depending on the prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HouseFull from '../HouseFull';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';


test('check HouseFull Render', () => {

const div = document.createElement('div');
ReactDOM.render(<HouseFull />, div);
});

it('Check for prop = true', () => {


const wrapper = shallow(<HouseFull hasSeat={true}/>);
expect(wrapper.text().toLowerCase()).toEqual('vacant');  

});

it('Check for prop = false', () => {


const wrapper = shallow(<HouseFull hasSeat={false}/>);

expect(wrapper.text().toLowerCase()).toEqual('housefull');  
//expect(wrapper.contains(<div>HouseFull</div>)).toEqual(true);  

});
```

This is the test file of my question please fetch the details from here..
Thankyou

Comment: Could you please add what all approaches you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use create the functional component for the same

```
function HouseFull(props) {
    const divText = props.hasSeat ? 'Vacant' : 'Housefull';
    return <div>{ divText }</div>;
}
```

If you want, you can use the es6 class as well, both are equivalent.

```
class HouseFull extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const divText = this.props.hasSeat ? 'Vacant' : 'Housefull';
    return <div>{ divText }</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Need help very urgent please let me know the solution of above problem.

Comment: @umang, what is the issue exactly, if you want to create the component, the above answer should suffice.

Comment: Actually, I am facing an error at  check HouseFull Render (18ms), Check for prop = true (3ms),                                                                                             Check for prop = false (1ms)

Answer (score -1):

This goes for the rendering part.

```
ReactDOM.render(
<HouseFull hasSeat={true} />
document.getElementById("root") );
```

You can change the value of hasSeat as needed (true or false) to get the appropriate outputs.

Comment: I assume the question asked how to build such a `HouseFull` component.